# Rails complicated class method chaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you write a complicated class method that applies to whatever it's being chained to? Let me explain: a simple class method such as:

```
def self.despondent
  where(despondent: true)
end
```

can be easily chained:

```
User.desperate.despondent.disillusioned
```

But what if you've got a complicated class method such as:

```
def self.friendly_dogs(user)
  @dogs1 = Dog.none
  @dogs2 = Dog.none
  if user.has_dog
    users = User.friends.where(has_dog: true)
    @dogs1 = Dog.where(user_id: users.ids)
  end
  if user.wife.has_dog
    users = user.wife.friends.where(has_dog: true)
    @dogs2 = Dog.where(user_id: users.ids)
  end
  return @dogs1.or(@dogs2).distinct
end
```

How would you write this so you can place it anywhere in the chain? And in the following example would select only the friendly_dogs from all poodles that are 1 year old:

```
@dogs = Dog.where(breed: "poodle").where(age: "1").friendly_dogs.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Comment: This `friendly_dogs` method might technically be chainable but discards the state up to that point. Use `where` directly instead of `Dog.where` - this will _add on_ to the query instead of starting a new one

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean use `where` directly?

Comment: Also, just to pick at nits, `.friendly_dogs.paginate` will throw an error because `.friendly_dogs` requires a `user` argument.

Comment: have you tried it? `friendly_dogs` returns an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` so you should be able to chain other methods that return `ActiveRecord::Relation`. btw you don't need the keyword `return`, it's automatic.

Comment: How'd this turn out?

Comment: Yes, it worked. There's nothing wrong with it! (apart from the paginate user argument - thanks jvillian). There was a stupid error elsewhere I hadn't picked up. I think I should probably delete this question, it isn't any use to anyone.